# Typefaces in which numbers look great for sale offers, discounts, price tags, and similar

Tags: typography, font-recommendation, typefaces

I am looking for a typeface, no make that **more than one** typeface in which **numbers look nice and appealing.** I want to use these typefaces when designing vouchers and stuff like that, I get a lot of work in that area, and I’m stuck with Georgia.

The typeface will be used on price tags, vouchers and discount offers for generic products on shops with no brand guidelines whatsoever, your average mall local shops, mom & pop type of shops that don’t know what a brand is and don’t want to know. They just want numbers that look good. The text *5%* needs to look that good that you “want it now” just by itself, with no other tricks.

For more than a year now I’ve been using Georgia for that, I kinda got bored of it and I’m on the look for a new typeface.

Georgia (for those that don't know it):

[image]

Comment: I would recommend a tall and narrow sans serif typeface, I find that they convey a good feeling when viewed ...

Comment: If you are bored, try searching Dribbble for [number](http://dribbble.com/search?q=number) or [numbers](http://dribbble.com/search?q=numbers)

Comment: I've just received this article by email: http://bit.ly/2tdZDKN
20 Best Number Fonts for Displaying Stylish Numbers

Answer (score 5):

I can't recommend any because I have no idea what "nice and sexy" mean to you. Nor, I'll bet, would you find three clients who all agree on what those mean in a typeface.

Beware the urge to change something just because you're bored. It's not a reason to change. If the *customers* are bored, that might be a reason, but sameness has advantages when it comes to communicating a simple idea like a number. Get too original, and your choice of typeface can distract from the message -- always a bad thing unless your typeface *is* the message.

Choose a face because it is readable and because it fits in the context of the text face and your overall design. Tall and skinny for a tall, skinny price list, fat or extended for a wide layout with a wide-body text treatment, boring and conservative for an annual report or accounting summary. A piece designed to look like a 19th Century advertising flyer and illustrated with woodcuts would probably look best with a Cheltenham, but that would look thoroughly out of place in a high tech flyer.

You should be able to articulate your design choices, not on the basis of subjective "feel" or vague "this works for me" criteria, but considerations that make logical and practical design sense.

You can have plenty of fun doing it, but don't make a sense of fun or "sexiness" a reason in itself unless it fits the message of the piece you're designing.

Comment: the typefaces will be used in the price tags, vouchers and discount offers for generic products on shops with no brand guidelines whatsoever, tour average mall local shops, mom&pop type of shops that don't know what a brand is and DON'T want to know, they just want sexy numbers(I've edited the question about sexy and all that, people get quickly offended by simple words...especially in the west part of the globe, apparently farts smell better in that part of the world ;)

Comment: The point is that words like "appealing" "sexy" "exciting" mean nothing when it comes to considering a typeface in isolation from any design, color, etc. Garamond or Georgia can be exciting in the right context, even Helvetica has know the odd breathless moment. Even the "appeal" of a particular typeface would depend on the specific product and who would buy it.